# How to fix JHipster integration test?

Tags: jhipster

I'm using JHipster version 4.14.3
I have created a basic monolith app selecting all of the default options.
Next I import a simple jdl file using command `jhipster import-jdl Model.jdl`
The contents of the jdl file is as follows:

```
entity PhoneContact {
    phoneNumber         String required pattern('/\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}/'),
    isMobile            Boolean
}
```

Next I want to generate a docker file using the following command:
`mvnw package -Pprod dockerfile:build`

This starts the build process, which fails in the Test phase.
It seems that the test failures are related to the the pattern on the phoneNumber, because when I import the model with the pattern commented out then I don't get the same test failures.
The generated test class `t.j.t3.web.rest.PhoneContactResourceIntTest` includes the following two declarations:

```
//    private static final String DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER = "0287146-2.1)0 0602";
//    private static final String UPDATED_PHONE_NUMBER = "586) .589(1";

    private static final String DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER = "0123456789";
    private static final String UPDATED_PHONE_NUMBER = "9876543210";
```

However even when I replace the declarations with much simpler values the tests continue to fail with the same errors.
The stacktrace for the first generated test `createPhoneContact` is as follows:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<400>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:665)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
>     at
>   t.j.t3.web.rest.PhoneContactResourceIntTest.createPhoneContact(PhoneContactResourceIntTest.java:107)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not match the generated values.  In your case, it expects a phone number to start with a `\` character.  You should also not surround regex in JDL files by quotes ([according to the JDL documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#entitydeclaration)).

> JHipster generates unit tests that work for generic entities, without knowing your validation rules: it is possible that the generated tests do not pass the validation rules. In that case, you will need to update the sample values used in your unit tests, so that they pass the validation rules. - https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm using JHipster-IDE to edit the jdl file and came across an issue with the regex syntax, raised the issue as https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-ide/issues/181.  I'm not looking to start with a \ , I want to start with an optional +, but that's a reserved char in regex so needs to be escaped with \. I made a test case in java for String PATTERN = "\\+?[0-9. ()-]{10,25}"; which gives expected results, not sure how to specify this in JDL. Perhaps I need to wait for the new grammar to be released.